# Element not visible selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape content from this [site](http://www.ospedaleuniverona.it/ecm/home/per-il-paziente/unita-operative). To go into next page, i tried clicking the next page button on the bottom of the page. I also tried to change the page via dropdown but i get error as `Element not visible`

I even tried using actionchain as to get through the next page as :

```
 act = ActionChains(self.driver)
 select_text=act.move_to_element(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='pagination-group']/select[@id='pagination-select']"))
 select_text.click().perform()
 time.sleep(4)
 option_text = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='pagination-group']/select[@id='pagination-select']/option")
 for o in option_text:
        if o.text in ('2','3','4','5','6'):
            o.click()
```

but again i get error as `line 47, in parse if o.text in ('2','3','4','5','6'):'
 StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up`

Answer (score 0):

Your initial approach,
`$("a",text:"Pagina successiva").click()` is probably the best.

This looks quite straight forward to fail. Maybe the links are generated from JS or something? Try adding a sleep in the test before trying to click, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium `Select` provides you methods to get `options` from a drop down webelement. You might want to make use of that, rather than trying to get options on your own.

Try,

```
selectElement = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select#pagination-select")
options = Select(selectElement).options;

for o in options:
    if o.text in ('2','3','4','5','6'):
        o.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the link you are looking for exists twice on the page. The first instance is hidden at the top of the page. One way to get around this is to find a container element that exists only on the bottom of the page. You can use this selector to click on the element you want. I just tested it and it works.

```
driver.get("http://www.ospedaleuniverona.it/ecm/home/per-il-paziente/unita-operative")
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#pagination-container-dest a[title='Pagina successiva']").click()
```